# Accesing data from NAS on IIS server

Tags: javascript, php, html, iis, nas

I am trying to show images from my NAS on my website that is running on an IIS server.
I have made a virtual directory and i have successfully linked my nas to the server.
Now everytime i try to load an image onto my html page i get the error:
"HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" errorcode: 0x80070005

i've read online that this means that i don't have acces to the file...
Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried so many different things but it still wont work..
I have been searching on this problem for the last couple of days.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs for one of the following reasons:

- You're using IIS on a computer that is running Windows. Additionally,
  you configure the website to use Universal Naming Convention (UNC)
  pass-through authentication to access a remote UNC share.
- The IIS_IUSRS group doesn't have the appropriate permissions for the
  ApplicationHost.config file, the Web.config file, or the virtual or
  application directories of IIS.

Resolution

Use one of the following methods:

- Don't configure the website to use UNC pass-through authentication to
  access the remote UNC share. Instead, specify a user account that has
  the appropriate permissions to access the remote UNC share.
- Grant the Read permission to the IIS_IUSRS group for the
  ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file. To do it, follow these
  steps:

1.In Windows Explorer, locate the folder that contains the ApplicationHost.config file that is associated with the website, or locate the virtual directories or the application directories that contain the Web.config file that is associated with the website.

- Note

  The Web.config file may not be in the virtual directories or the
  application directories in IIS. Even in this situation, you have to
  follow these steps.
  2.Right-click the folder that contains the ApplicationHost.config file, or right-click the virtual or application directories that may contain the Web.config file.

3.Select **Properties**.

4.Select the **Security** tab, and then Select **Edit**.

5.Select **Add**.

6.In the **Enter the object names to select** box, type **`<computername>`\IIS_IUSRS**, select **Check Names**, and then select **OK**.

Note

`<Computername>` is a placeholder for the computer name.

7.Select the **Read** check box, and then select **OK**.

8.In the **Properties** dialog box for the folder, select **OK**.

- Note

  Make sure that the folder properties are inherited by the
  ApplicationHost.config and Web.config files so that IIS_IUSRS has the
  Read permission for those files.
  Here is the reference: [HRESULT code 0x80070005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x80070005)